# Function used for assigning something as an object's property?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Came across this piece of code recently:

```js
const fetchMock = async (name, type="success") => {
  const response = await fetch(someUrl);
  let mock = await response.json();
  mock = mock[type];
  mock.json = () => mock.data;
  return mock;
}
```

I have trouble understanding why, on line 5, we use a `function` to assign the `mock.data` to `mock.json`. Can't we simply write `mock.json` = `mock.data`? How is it different?

P. S. I don't have any idea about the kind of data it is receiving.

Comment: Maybe because a library or another part of the code expects the `mock` to have a function named `json`, so they can call it as a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with the async JSON fetching stuff. In the end, `mock` is just an object which has a `data` property. It also needs a `json` property that yields the `data` property.

So a reduced code sample would look like this:

```
const mock = {
  data: {
    "someKey": "someValue"
  }
};

mock.json = () => mock.data;
```

Assume that `mock.json` is set exactly once, and `mock.data` is mutated or updated. Then, `mock.json = mock.data` will only work correctly if `mock.data` is [an object that stays the same reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104500/4642212).

```
const mock = {
  data: {
    "someKey": "someValue"
  }
};

mock.json = mock.data;
console.log(mock.json); // { "someKey": "someValue" }, as expected
// …
mock.data.someKey = "someOtherValue"
console.log(mock.json); // { "someKey": "someOtherValue" }, as expected

// Either of these reassignments will break up the connection between `mock.json` and `mock.data`:
mock.data = {"newKey": "something"};
mock.data = "Something else";

console.log(mock.json); // { "someKey": "someOtherValue" }, no longer updated
```

This doesn’t matter for `mock.json = () => mock.data`, though, as the function just returns the *current* value of `mock.data`.

Comment: Thanks! That seems accurate. I guess I have to properly read how passing by values and reference works. Since JS is the only language I know, it's hard to get when people try to explain things in JS by comparing with other languages, so the link didn't help me much. But I got the point.